# Google home ability to make http requests

Tags: http, google-home

I have a (non-Google, non-intelligent) device that can be controlled by a simple http command. Can I write an app for my Google Home Mini that can respond to my verbal request and send the http command to this device (on my local LAN)?

for example

http://192.168.1.100/action

Thanks in advance
Garry

Answer (score 2):

You can create a Smart Home action that you can run on any Assistant-enabled device (such as a Google Home Mini) that sends the http command to your home device. To run it locally, you can use the [Local Home SDK](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/local).

There is a [local home SDK sample](https://github.com/actions-on-google/smart-home-local) available based around controlling lights that would be a good starting point for you to reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid any SDK using IFTTT. It supports simple commands for Google home

You can add a trigger with a couple of parameters. You’d need to add a Webhook action. You might have to make something public that can call your endpoint, but that’s a lot simpler than using the Google SDK.

Comment: If the command requires any sort of variable input (e.g. "do $ on $") where the dollar signs are some kind of parameter that is passed along, then unfortunately Google is now retiring that capability in IFTTT. I used to use it to add stuff to my Todoist shopping list (without having to dive into a painful conversation with an app).

Comment: I just got that an email minutes ago